# C# eventhandler never gets subscribers

Tags: c#, .net, event-handling

I have a controller class and a manager class.

I want my manager class to call a function from my controller to trigger an event.

My controller looks something like this:

```
public class Controller{
    public Controller(Mgr mgr)
    {
        m_mgr = mgr;
        m_mgr.schedulerReload += reloadScheduler;
    }

    void reloadScheduler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReloadSchedulerQueue();
    }
}
```

where ReloadSchedulerQueue is the function I want to trigger from my event.

my manager class looks like this

```
public class Manager{
    public event EventHandler schedulerReload;

    public void somefunction() {
      //do something
      schedulerReload(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this I can see that the schedulerReload event is getting a null reference exception, im assuming because there is no one subscribed to my event. However, I can clearly see while stepping through my code that the constructor, and the line

```
m_mgr.schedulerReload += reloadScheduler;
```

is clearly hit multiple times before somefunction() is called. I know I can handle this exception by checking my eventhandler before calling it, but I don't know why my eventhandler is not getting subscribed to.

What am I missing here?

Comment: "...is clearly hit multiple times before" but for which instance of `Manager`? Is a handler added for the exact instance you later call `somefunction()` on?

Comment: You sure that you invoke the event on the same instance that you've subscribed to? and also best practice to invoke is `schedulerReload?.Invoke...`

Comment: easier if you post a reproducible example - there is a disparity between `Manager` / `Mgr`. Also need entry point.

Comment: The Manager instance that you have there what scope does it have? (Singleton,Transient etc)